# javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider

Tags: jsf, wildfly, mojarra

I using: Maven 3.3.1, Java SE 1.8, JavaServerFaces 2.2, JPA 2.0, Spring 4.1.6, Hibernate 4.3.2.Final and Wildfly.
I'm new to J2EE, please give me detailed instructions.

My stacktrace:

```
     09:52:31,461 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-4) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Class org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357) [javax.faces-2.0.10.jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:220) [javax.faces-2.0.10.jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:193) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
at com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProviderFactory.createAnnotationProvider(AnnotationProviderFactory.java:78) [javax.faces-2.0.10.jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.<init>(ConfigManager.java:752) [javax.faces-2.0.10.jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:330) [javax.faces-2.0.10.jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT]
... 10 more

    09:52:31,472 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Ear_Project: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Ear_Project: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Class org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:222)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Class org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:287)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:193)
... 7 more
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:   CONFIGURATION FAILED! Class org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:220)
... 9 more
    Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
at com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProviderFactory.createAnnotationProvider(AnnotationProviderFactory.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.<init>(ConfigManager.java:752)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:330)
... 10 more
```

Comment: JandexAnnotationProvider in fact extends from AnnotationProvider class and such error may be caused if both classes are loaded via different classloaders. I think you have to exclude your jsf-api-???.jar and jsf-impl-???.jar from beeing deployed with your application. Use jsf libraries, provided by application server.

Comment: Yes, I had excluded jsf, I deleted it and now it works

Comment: Please mark your question as answered with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30369021/1324287), so that other Stackoverflow users can get it helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JandexAnnotationProvider` in fact extends from `AnnotationProvider` class and such error may be caused if both classes are loaded via different classloaders.

I think you have to exclude your `jsf-api-???.jar` and `jsf-impl-???.jar` from beeing deployed with your application. Use jsf libraries, provided by application server.

To achieve it with maven, just set `<scope>provided</scope>` to the `jsf-api` and `jsf-impl` dependencies in your `pom.xml`